# How to define a subdomain in nsd3

Tags: dns, installation, subdomain

nsd3 is very little-known but super-lightweight and stable DNS server which makes it a great alternative to bind9 for low-end boxes. There is a very good tutorial here on  [how to set up nsd3](https://forum.ramhost.us/bbs/viewtopic.php?pid=1032) on debian server.

My problem is that I need to set up a subdomain subd1.mydomain.com that is going to be severed on another VPS. I tried to add

subdmn1.mydomain.com. IN 1.2.3.5
(assuming that my destination IP is 1.2.3.5 different from current machine's IP 1.2.3.4) Then after running

```
nsdc rebuild
service nsd3 restart
```

the subdmn1.mydomain.com fails to resolve to the IP. Any clues will be much appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? If you already had an entry for subdmn1 or subd1, did you wait for the TTL to expire before re-testing?

Comment: The error that I can see in my syslog are "can't bind udp socket: Address already in use" and then "server initialization failed, nsd could not be started". However the dns server still works for the main domain. TTL is set to 3600, and I am trying for over 4 hours.

Comment: However, one strange thing that I see is that when I try to test resolution using dig command, the serial number is not updated to the latest serial number that I have reseted.

Answer (score 1):

nsd3 accepts BIND-style zone files, so in your zone file for mydomain.com, you can add a line that looks like this:

```
subdomain1    IN    A    1.2.3.5
```

That makes `subdomain1.mydomain.com` resolve to 1.2.3.5, while your normal A record can point to the 1.2.3.4 IP.

You have to take care however that you defined the $ORIGIN domain correctly, otherwise it won't work. That means that your domain name must include a period at the end, like this: `mydomain.com.`

I personally always use `sudo zonec -v` for compiling the zone file database, because that gives a verbose output with all errors (if any) clearly displayed.

For a very thorough example of zone files and DNS configuration, you can also check out: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to increment serial number? I on the other hand keep forgetting to run 'nsdc rebuild'.